# display all categories and subcategories like aliExpress

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to display all categories and subcategories like AliExpress. I try to create new module, but I don't know how to get all data from category table. Anyone help me please!
[image]

this is my displayController

```
$allCategories = Category::getNestedCategories(null, $this->context->language->id);
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'allCategories' , $allCategories );
$this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
```

but get only Root and Home category

Comment: I should works, add `Tools::p($allCategories);` in your code to see/debug categories tree

Comment: Are you sure all your categories are active and your user have the right permissions to see it?

Comment: where can i add Tools::p($allCategories); @Sergii P?

Comment: @FirstProgramer after first line. Tools::p() = var_dump() just stylized, I proposed you to debug your code.

Comment: i just want to shop categories are active @ Florian Lemaitre

Comment: okay i test already using var_dump()

and i get data like this

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61DHBrjHyi5c3B0ZGdUdE1fOUU/view?usp=sharing